# Is Captcha useless using a "Facebook Sign in" registering process?

Tags: facebook, captcha, spam

Does the Facebook Sign In process prevent some potential spamming bots ?
Should I put a captcha before allowing a Facebook Sign In process?

Comment: When you use facebook sign in , facebook takes care of all. Next time you sign in , enter 3-4 invalid passwords :)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can break any Captcha. But breaking it gets harder as the Captcha gets more complicated. It will prevent spambots made by people who cannot break the Captcha, and I'm fairly sure that a company like Facebook does have good Captchas.

Comment: Sometimes even I can't read the CAPTCHA, lol:) I get irritated by this quickly.

Comment: Yes, I don't think CAPTCHAs will survive much longer, because Computers will soon be able to break any CAPTCHA... even those that we cannot read.